# Apache james beta5 in maven repository

Tags: maven, james

I started to work in the apache james upgrade from beta3 to beta5. In [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.james/james-server-mailets) the version is not still online, do you know when will it be available? And what about the M1 and M2?

Comment: Best is to ask on the mailing list of Apache James. Or mail on the mailing list for request to deploy to Maven Central. May be there is a SNAPSHOT available?

Comment: I will ask there and comment here the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long delay from beta 4 in 2012, [3.0 beta 5 was released in late 2016](https://james.apache.org/james/update/2016/11/19/james-3.0.html).

A final [3.0 was released in mid 2017](https://james.apache.org/james/update/2017/07/20/james-3.0.html) and, as of early 2019, the latest release is [3.2.0](https://james.apache.org/james/update/2018/11/14/james-3.2.0.html).

That latest release is [available through Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.james%20AND%20v:3.2.0), along with the previous versions.